# Match cell value from two sheets and paste where the value is met, starting from one cell below

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, I'm using Microsoft Office Excel 2007 and I read the forums but this seems impossible for me. I have the current code which copies a sheet and adds a day to the date and also copies a range of cells containing the important information from the sheet to be able to paste it in a calendar with realtime information and I need it to paste where the date is the same and one cell below the value which could be located in any place in a certain range.

```
Sub CopierPetete()
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
        After:=ActiveSheet
    'update date
        [J1].Value = [J1].Value + 1

   'THIS IS MY POOR ATTEMPT TO MAKE IT WORK
    If Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1:K100").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Value Then _  

        ActiveSheet.Range("AA100:AC121").Select
            Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet5").Select
            Sheets("Sheet5").Pictures.Paste Link:=True

    End If

End Sub
```

I need it to match the value in the `ActiveAheet` cell `J1` with any cell on `Sheet5`, and paste as `Pictures.Paste Link=True` (or, if you have a better idea for a way to display real-time information) at the place where the value is met on `Sheet5`, one cell below.

Here's [a link to the project](http://www.mediafire.com/?olsvdd22dxmslrz)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, what you intend to do is to *check if the value of the ActiveSheet > cell J1 exists in the Sheet named "Sheet5" within the range A1 to K100*. Meaninly, if Excel finds any cell withing A1 to K100 matching the J1 value, copy-paste the picture.

Here is a try:

```
Sub CopierPetete()
    Dim rFind as Range

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
        After:=ActiveSheet
    'update date
        [J1].Value = [J1].Value + 1

    'Find returns a range object, so we use Set
    Set rFind = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1:K100").Find(ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not rFind is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("AA100:AC121").Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Range(rFind.Address).Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Pictures.Paste Link:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The pictures.paste only works with Link = True, with Link:=True it comes up an error but that is not relevant. Thank you very much for your reply but the executed code comes up with '1004' "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" Please help!

Comment: Also I need it to paste in the "Sheet5" one cell below where it has found the J1 value. Is that possible?

Comment: Also the value provided is in date formatting, does that make any difference?

Comment: The link to the project can be found here mediafire com/?0d06ivmdsonq0kh

Comment: I've edited my answer. Activating cells is probably not the nicest way but I didn't manage to use the `Pictures.Paste` **and** changing the destination range.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time I really appreciate it but if pictures.paste is the problem then how can I paste the "AA100:AC121" range in the "Sheet5" and make the update every time I change the values in them? I tried the current code and it doesn't do anything, no errors but only makes a new sheet and doesn't copy anything.

Comment: I've checked it and it seemed to work on my example. Try step by step and see what doesn't work

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you very much! I tried removing the code that copies the worksheet and it works without that, so I'll try figuring something out. Thank you again you're a life saver!

Comment: The problem was that it didn't recognize the date formatting, I just made another cell with 1 2 3 and put that next to the cell with the date and it works perfectly! Thank you very much, I am forever in your debt. If there's something I can help you with please let me know, I do graphics!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't hesitate to share your knowledge in your turn here or elsewhere :)